# Why AWS Lambda function invoked multiple times for a single event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I am trying to create AWS Lambda function that does following process.

- Receive S3 "Put" event
- Get fileA from S3
- Get fileB from S3 that invoked lambda
- Launch just one EC2 instance
- Create tags for the new EC2 instance

**Problem: Multiple(5) instances are launched unexpectedly.**

An instance is successfully created, but 4 other instances are also launched. 5 instances in total are launched.

**Logs**

In the Log Streams for this function, I found 4 Streams for this invocation. Each Stream doesn't show any errors or exceptions, but it seems that the function is executed repeatedly.

**Trial**

I guessed that the function has been timed out and then re-run.

Then, I changed `Timeout` from 5s to 60s and put a file on S3.
It somehow effected. Only 2 Log Streams appeared, first one shows that the function has been executed just once, second shows the function has been executed twice. Number of launched instances is 3.

However, I have no idea why multiple(3) instances are launched.

Any comments are welcome! 
Thank you in advance :-)

**My Lambda function**

My Lambda function is following. (It's simplified to hide credential informations but it doesn't lose its basic structure)

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

function composeParams(data, config){
  var block_device_name = "/dev/xvdb";
  var security_groups = [
    "MyGroupName"
  ];
  var key_name = 'mykey';
  var security_group_ids = [
    "sg-xxxxxxx"
  ];
  var subnet_id = "subnet-xxxxxxx";

  // Configurations for a new EC2 instance
  var params = {
    ImageId: 'ami-22d27b22',      /* required */
    MaxCount: 1,                  /* required */
    MinCount: 1,                  /* required */
    KeyName: key_name,
    SecurityGroupIds: security_group_ids,
    InstanceType: data.instance_type,
    BlockDeviceMappings: [
      {
        DeviceName: block_device_name,
        Ebs: {
          DeleteOnTermination: true,
          Encrypted: true,
          VolumeSize: data.volume_size,
          VolumeType: 'gp2'
        }
      }
    ],
    Monitoring: {
      Enabled: false              /* required */
    },
    SubnetId: subnet_id,
    UserData: new Buffer(config).toString('base64'),
    DisableApiTermination: false,
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: 'stop',
    DryRun: data.dry_run,
    EbsOptimized: false
  };

  return params;
}

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  // Get the object from the event
  var s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
  var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

  // Get fileA
  var paramsA = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key
  };
  s3.getObject(paramsA, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var dataA = JSON.parse(String(data.Body));

      // Get fileB
      var paramsB = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: 'config/config.yml'
      };
      s3.getObject(paramsB, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
          var config = data.Body;
          /* Some process */

          // Launch EC2 Instance
          var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ region: REGION, apiVersion: '2015-04-15' });
          var params = composeParams(dataA, config);
          ec2.runInstances(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err, err.stack);
            } else {
              console.log(data);

              // Create tags for instance
              for (var i=0; i<data.Instances.length; i++){
                var instance = data.Instances[i];
                var params = {
                  Resources: [                /* required */
                    instance.InstanceId
                  ],
                  Tags: [                     /* required */
                    {
                      Key: 'Name',
                      Value: instance_id
                    },
                    {
                      Key: 'userID',
                      Value: dataA.user_id
                    }
                  ],
                  DryRun: dataA.dry_run
                };
                ec2.createTags(params, function(err, data) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                  } else {
                    console.log("Tags created.");
                    console.log(data);
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Callbacks in your `for loop` won't get executed as you expect. Consider using `promises` after all callbacks complete.

Answer (score 15):

Solved.

Adding `context.succeed(message);` to the last part of the nested callback prevents the repeated execution of the function.

```
            ec2.createTags(params, function(err, data) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
                context.fail('Failed');
              } else {
                console.log("Tags created.");
                console.log(data);
                context.succeed('Completed');
              }
            });
```

Comment: There are other conditions that may cause your function to trigger more than one time. You should expect "at-least-once" invocation.

Comment: The ``runInstances`` function takes an optional ``ClientToken`` parameter which makes it possible to get idempotent instance launches.  If you can find a way to associate a unique string value with ``fileB`` (the file that generates the event) you could pass this unique string  as the ``ClientToken`` and guarantee that only 1 instance would be launched.

Comment: Beware, your `for loop` is incorrect. Callbacks won't get executed as you expect. You should use `promises` and fire `context.done` after all callbacks returned.

Comment: @ai0307 had same problem. this fixed it thanks! ps: mark it as answer please.

Answer (score 2):

Check in cloudwatch event that context.aws_request_id value for each invokation. If it is

1. ***same*** than it is retry because aws function got some error raised.
   make your lambda idempotent
2. ***different*** than it is because of connection timeout from your aws
   lambda client. check aws client configuration request timeout and
   connect timeout values.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the newer runtime (Node.JS v4.3). Call

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

before calling

```
callback(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maximum Event Age**

When a function returns an error before execution, Lambda returns the event to the queue and attempts to run the function again for up to 6 hours by default. With Maximum Event Age, you can configure the lifetime of an event in the queue from 60 seconds to 6 hours. This allows you to remove any unwanted events based on the event age.

**Maximum Retry Attempts**

When a function returns an error after execution, Lambda attempts to run it two more times by default. With Maximum Retry Attempts, you can customize the maximum number of retries from 0 to 2. This gives you the option to continue processing new events with fewer or no retries.

under the **Configuration** > **Asynchronous invocation** > **Retry Attempts**
you can set it to **0-2**

[image]

[image]

**Source:**
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-max-retry-attempts-event-age-asynchronous-invocations/